# Requests Error: No connection adapters were found

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm currently new to programming and I'm following along on one of Qazi tutorials and I'm on a section for web scraping but unfortunately I'm getting errors that I can't seem to find a solution for, can you please help me out. Thanks

The error code is bellow.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\Vaughan\Qazi\Web Scrapping\webscraping.py", line 6, in <module>
    page = requests.get(
  File "C:\Users\vaugh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vaugh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vaugh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vaugh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 640, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "C:\Users\vaugh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 731, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '['https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=34.09979000000004&lon=-118.32721499999997#.XkzZwCgzaUk']'
[Finished in 1.171s]
```

My line of code is as follows

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import pandas as pd
import lxml 

page = requests.get('https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=34.09979000000004&lon=-118.32721499999997#.XkzZwCgzaUk')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

week = soup.find(id='seven-day-forecast-body')

print(week)
```

Comment: This code as is works perfectly on my machine. Are you sure you are running this same code? that error usually means you have either forgotten the `https://` or `http://` or you have a typo there

Comment: I've checked all of the lines of code and they all seem to be fine. I've tried running the code on both Atom and Pycharm and it gives me the same error on both for some reason. The error show me that it has to do with page = requests.get and I've installed request via Pycharm terminal and CMD as admin.

Comment: Great It's working. I tried restarting my computer to see if anything needed to be updated and saved at it looks like the necessary pip installations got saved I'm guessing, but its working now. Thanks for the response plumSempy